# How to convert the column of excel from mm:ss.0[ 57:12.6] to yyyy/mm//dd hh:mm:ss[6/26/2013 4:50:19 PM]

Tags: java

Hi Friends iam having an issue while reading the date from excel,the value in the excel is shown as 57:12.6 but when we click on the value on the excel field it is showing as 6/27/2013  9:57:13 AM in formula bar can any body tell how to read the column and convert from short fromat[57:12.6] to long format[6/27/2013 9:57:13] using a java code.

Comment: which API you are using to read Excel sheet ?

Comment: Iam just reading it into a string and trying to process it

Comment: can you post your code snippet in question

Comment: which api implies the third party api used to read the excel file

Answer (score 0):

**Reading date cell value by [Apachi POI](http://poi.apache.org/).**

If you know a cell value is a date, you can go for `hSSFCell.getDateCellValue()`directly.

See method document [getDateCellValue](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.html#getDateCellValue%28%29) for more details.